# Is there a way to get all html elements with the same tag in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in my index.shtml, I want to change the text of all `<button>` in page after user checking a checkbox. I tried this in the checkbox `onclick` method:

```
    @functions{  

          private void Invisibilize()
          {
              List<HtmlButton> buttons = new List<HtmlButton>();
              buttons = this.HtmlControls.OfType<HtmlButton>().ToList();// error
              foreach (HtmlButton button in buttons)
              {
                  button.Style="Color:red";
                  button.InnerTex = "Currently not selectable";
              } //end foreach
          }// end method       
      }
```

It does not work. Error says the page:

> does not contain a definition for 'HtmlControls'

I already imported all the libraries needed

```
@using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

HTML markup:

```
<input id="cb60" type="checkbox" onclick="Invisibilize()" />
    <label for="cb60">Disable the buttons</label>
```

Comment: This appears to be Web Forms code, not MVC. And you need javascript if you want to respond to client side events.

Comment: MVC has no notion of controls.  You want CSS and maybe Javascript.

Comment: You should paste the html markup as well. Javascript is probably the way to go here but to help you we need the html markup.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can take the JavaScript way as the answer if it can do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible via the way you're trying. MVC works differently than Web Forms. By the time you have a fully rendered HTML document, it's already on it's way back to the client. You need to use JavaScript to do this. That's pretty straight-forward though:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].innerHTML = 'new button text';
}
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery:

```
$('button').each(function () {
    $(this).html('new button text');
});
```

**EDIT**

The function syntax you have is incorrect. In fact, I'm not sure where you even got the idea for that syntax. In JavaScript a function is declared thus:

```
function myAwesomeFunction() {
    ...
}
```

There's no accessibility keyword on a JavaScript function because JavaScript has no concept of method accessibility; everything is public within scope. There's also no return type on a JavaScript function because JavaScript is duck-typed. Also the `@functions` bit you have needs to go. I'm not sure what that is.

So, what you should have is something like:

```
<script>
    function Invisiblize() {
        // code to alter buttons
    }
</script>
```

Or, you can just directly bind to the event and put the code there, without a separate named function:

```
$('#checkbox').on('click', function () {
    // code to alter buttons
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The JavaScript you provided actually changed all buttons' text right after the page is loaded. I want it to be an event handler and change the text after checking the checkbox (markup is in the OP). So I surround the function with `function Invisiblize(){ }` but now it does not work any more.

Comment: I was just providing you the relevant code to change all the buttons' text, not implying that you should just plop that as-is on your page. If you want it to happen only after a certain event fires, then just place the code inside the event handler.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. The event attribute for the checkbox should be `onclick` not `onchange`. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: the `@functions` block is for declaring functions in razor/C# code in the view. I got rid of `Invicibilize()` in the block and replaced it with your JS in the `<script>` block.